# methology for keeping different backbone models in sync

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I've tried to describe my problem in the below illustration.

[image]

When the page loads, a javascript object is parsed and becomes my backbone model called **obj model**. This **obj model** is passed along to many different independent and modular **submodules** that make use of the data in different ways.

Everything works great except for when I'm dealing with collections. To give the user the ability to manage "Photos" and "Comments" I need to create a separate **collection/model** data structure for them.

How should I sync back the changes to my "obj model"?

```
class Obj extends Backbone.DeepModel

class Comment extends Backbone.DeepModel

class CommentCollection extends Backbone.Collection
    model: Comment

class Photo extends Backbone.DeepModel

class PhotoCollection extends Backbone.Collection
    model: Photo
```

Answer (score 1):

You're obj model should be externalized.

```
App.module("Entities",function(Entities,App,Backbone,Marionette,$,_){

    "use strict";

    //these are locally scoped, so they aren't accessable by the your app
    var Obj = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot:'api/obj',
    });

    var Data = {};

    var API = {
        //wrap request in deferred
        getObjById : function(id, reset){
            var deferred = $.Deferred();
            //returned cached data if we don't request refreshed data
            reset = reset || false;
            if (Data[id] && !reset) {
                return Data;
            }

            this._getObj(id, function(loadedObj) {
                //cache object
                Data[loadedObj.id] = loadedObj
                deferred.resolve(loadedObj);
            });

            return deferred.promise();
        },
        _getObj: function(id, callback) {
            var obj = new Obj({id:id});
            obj.fetch({success:callback});
        },
    };


    //Interface for mucking with Obj model
    App.reqres.setHandler("obj:getObj", function(id) {
        return API.getObjById(id);
    });
});
```

You can get an obj like so. If reset isn't passed in, it will be the cached version (all sub modules can refer to same obj just by passing in ID or w/e your criteria is for loading):

```
$.when(App.request('obj:getObj', 123)).done(function(loadedObj) {
  //show view, or do whatever
);
```

OR to get fresh data:

```
$.when(App.request('obj:getObj', 123, true)).done(function(loadedObj) {
  //show view, or do whatever
);
```

These are just examples of how to GET data.  You could extend the API and expose new handlers for UPDATING data.  You could either have each sub module's controller listen to the obj (by all listening to the same, cached obj model), or just request the most up to date obj model each time you need it.  This would be a round trip to the server if your cached data reflects the most recent changes. But then you have to worry about keeping things in sync.

Hope this helps